# How can I display the data I created in a linked list?

Tags: c

I think there is something wrong with my create.

```
void add(N *p) {
    N *current, *start;
    current = malloc(sizeof(p));
    scanf("%d", &current->data);
    current->next = NULL;

    if (p == NULL) {
        p = current;
        start = current;
    } else {
        start->next = current;
        start = current;
    }
}
```

I think that my `display()` is correct.

```
void display(N *p) {
    N *current;
    current = p;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("\n%d", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get ? what is the desired output ? what is your current output ?

Comment: nothing output ... if I input 1 then the program stop proccess return 0

Comment: I tried that malloc(sizeof(N)). The output is the same.

Comment: here's my structure..
 struct num{
  int data;
  struct num *next;
};
typedef struct num N;

int main(){
    N *head = NULL;
    add(head);
    display(head);

return 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems:

- function `add()` does not allocate the correct amount of memory. Use this method:

  ```
  current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
  ```
- The way you are inserting the newly allocated object into the list does not work: you modify `p`, which is an argument with local scope, and you set `start` which also has local scope.  No side effect is performed on the `N` pointer is the callers scope.
- Your `display` function is correct, but I would favor adding the newline at the end of the output instead of at the beginning.

Here is an updated version with a better API:

```
int add(N **headp) {
    N *current = calloc(sizeof(*current));
    if (current == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for new object\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &current->data) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot read value for new object\n");
        return -2;
    }
    current->next = *headp;
    *headp = current;
    return 0;
}

void display(const N *list) {
    for (const N *p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next) { 
        printf("%d\n", p->data);
    }
}
```

The `add` function is used this way from the caller:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct N {
    int data;
    struct N *next;
} N;

int main(void) {
    N *list = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (add(&list))
            break;
    }
    display(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i just found out head = add(head); it works. thank you for the tips. 
    
       int main(){
           N *head = NULL;
           head = add(head);
           display(head);
       return 0;
       }

Comment: @Willy: `head = add(head);` is not as powerful as `add(&head)` to provide detection of failure. `add(&head)` could return a boolean value indicating success or an `int` indicating an error code. I updated the code to reflect this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your `malloc(sizeof(p))` only returns enough space for a *pointer*. You instead want `malloc(sizeof(N))`.

Also, you need to return the new value of `p` instead of throwing it away at the end of `add()`. (Your `start` has a similar issue; pick one to be the head of your linked list.)

Comment: okay got it. How about in my display? is there something wrong?

Comment: @Willy Your `display()` looks fine. It's your `add()` that has issues.